# NSURLSession - data is nil

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsdata, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I've got a problem when trying to fetch data with NSURLSession delegate methods. I've come up with this error:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'"
```

What I do not understand is that

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

    CGFloat percentDone = (double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    NSLog(@"Pourcentage: %f", percentDone);
}
```

is returning 1.000000, and the following delegate method is called

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Parse the JSON that came in

    NSLog(@"DidComplete"); --> I can see this message

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in finishLoading: %@", error.localizedDescription); --> but this message is not displayed. There is no error, only data returning nil resulting in a crash...
    }
    else {
    ....
}
```

But the following methods are not called

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"DidReceiveResponse"); --> not displayed

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSLog(@"DidReceiveData. Data: %@", data); --> not displayed

    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [_downloadedData appendData:data];
}
```

however it should be called before the didCompleteWithError isn't it? I am assuming the other methods taking care of appending data cannot be called and then data is nil.

I am sure I can fetch the data on the server side since when I am using a block method (and not the delegate methods), the NSData corresponds to what I am looking for.

What is strange is that this error comes after I change the Configuration Session like this:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession2 = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/download_list.php"];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *dataTask = [defaultSession2 downloadTaskWithURL:url];
```

When it was like this, I could see the NSData that was retrieved from the server

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession2 dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if(error == nil) {
         NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"Data = %@",text); -> text corresponds to the data I am looking for
    }
}];
```

However it was impossible to call the delegate with a block.

Any idea how the "data" disappears? Or should I change something when not using the block?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's okay, I was stupid, it was a NSURLSessionDownloadTask instead of a NSURLSessionDataTask... However I have a strange message: nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28. Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything...

Comment: The "strange message" is a new issue. Delete the Q and create a new one. It is not the readers' task to grab together the real Q.

Comment: I have not really understood what is the goal with a new queue? I changed the dataTask and the delegate methods were called, thx.

Comment: Not "queue", but rather "question". He's saying that if you have a question about some weird log message, that's a completely different issue and should be posted as a separate question, not asked in comments underneath this question. It seems like the question here was "why am I not seeing my delegate methods called?", to which the answer is "because you used the completion handler rendition of `dataTaskWithURL`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `didReceiveResponse` and `didReceiveData` delegate methods will not be called if you call `dataTaskWithURL` like so:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession2 dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

You're supplying a completion handler, requesting it to capture the `response` and `data` for you. So, to do that, it won't call the delegate methods.

If you want your delegate methods to be called, you should just:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession2 dataTaskWithURL:url];
```

Frankly, though, you're not currently doing anything significant in those methods, so I'd wonder why you want to use the delegate methods rather than the completion handler. The completion handler pattern is simpler.

---

By the way, if you're going to use those methods, make sure that `didReceiveData` only appends. Instantiate the mutable data object in `didReceiveResponse`. It may take more than one `didReceiveData` call to receive the entire response, and your original code sample will truncate the results. You presumably want to do something like:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveResponse");                 // will now be displayed

    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"DidReceiveData. Data: %@", data);     // will now be displayed

    [_downloadedData appendData:data];
}
```